# Find the correction location in MapKit

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I am beginner to Xcode.I want to show the other location with pin not my current location.I have the latitude and longitude value.Now i use map view it only showing the current location.

```c
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    locationmanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationmanager setDelegate:self];

    [locationmanager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationmanager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MKMapViewClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html). Here is code I hope this will help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"Buckingham Palace" andCoordinate:location];
[self.map addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
[newAnnotation release];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 1500, 1500);
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
[mv selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
}
```